# float variable not updating while iterating through loop - C

Tags: c, arrays, iteration

I  have this while loop

```
while (p < numSchemes){
    totalg = 0;
    while (s < numComponents){
        totalg = totalg + (grades[s] * (weight[p][s] * .01) );
        s++;
    }

    printf("Grade using marking scheme #%d: %.02f\n", p, totalg);
    p++;
}
```

In the first loop, it successfully sums up the total and puts it in `totalg`
But after the second iteration, `totalg` it just prints out the result I got from the first iteration.
Can someone point out what I might be doing wrong here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post the whole code?

Comment: maybe the result just comes out the same

Answer (score 2):

You aren't resetting `s`. When the second iteration starts, `s == numComponents` (because the previous iteration kept incrementing it), so the second `while` loop is never run, and `totalg` is never changed.

You should:

1. Reset `s` every iteration (or even better, do as @JonathanLeffler suggests and use a `for` loop)
2. Possibly reset `totalg` (depending on what you want; it's impossible for me to tell without more context)
3. Learn how to use a debugger to step through the code, line by line

Comment: Congratulations on achieving 10k!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks! Sitting there at 9,999 was kinda fun.

Comment: Cornstalks, we can downvote you back there if that's what you _really_ want. Nah, just kidding, here's another +1 :-)

Comment: And, on a slightly more serious note, if the code use two nested `for` loops, both written idiomatically `for (p = 0; p < numSchemes; p++) { totalg = 0.0; for (s = 0; s < numComponents; s++) { ... } ... }`, then there wouldn't have been a problem in the first place.  (I'd prefer to declare the variable inside the loop: `for (int p = 0; ...)` but you need C99 or better support for that.)